# No module named 'mysql' python issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python, python-3.7

I am trying to create a sample python program which needs to connect to MySQL database.

```
import mysql.connector 

# opens the file file.txt in read mode
fileptr = open("sample-table","r")  

if fileptr:  
    print("file is opened successfully") 

#running a for loop   
for i in fileptr:  
    print(i) # i contains each line of the file 

#closes the opened file  
fileptr.close()
```

But I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check-db.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

It looks like the required module is not present. Is it possible to include and install the module without root access?

Comment: maybe this this helps you https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: @markkeven, I am able to download it but installing it requires root privileges. I am looking for the solution to include mysql without root

Comment: Isn't that what virtual environments are for? You should be able to use them to install stuff locally without requiring additional privileges.

Answer (score 1):

install pip like this:

```
apt install python-pip  #python 2
apt install python3-pip #python 3
```

Try install `mysql` using this command:

```
pip install pymysql
```

Comment: I am getting the error as `[username@archlinux ~]$ pip install pymysql
bash: pip: command not found`

Comment: Then use this: `python -m pip install pymysql`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am again getting the error as `/usr/bin/python: No module named pip`

Comment: Tried installing pip, but again error `sudo pacman -S python3-pip
error: target not found: python3-pip`

Comment: what about `sudo pacman -S python2-pip`? are you using python3 or 2 ?

Comment: I am using `Python 3.7.2`

Comment: so you should run `python3.7 -m pip install pymysql`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it installed but the error is same `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'`. Is there any way just to include the mysql library in the path rather than installation

Comment: Now you should run this file using `python3.7`, the default is running with `2.7`.